# undefined method in view, but works in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User, Question, and Answer models.

User `has_many :questions` and `has_many :answers`

Question `has_many :answers` and `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id"`

Answer `belongs_to :question, :foreign_key => "question_id"` and `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id"`

In console:

```
>> Question.find(2).answers.each{|a| p a.user.name}

=> "example user"
```

In view:

```
- @question.answers.each do |a|
  = a.user.name
```

However the view returns `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

In controller:

```
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
```

The id parameter is 2

If I switch the view to

```
Question.find(2).answers.each do |a|
  = a.user.name
```

Then the view displays correctly.

What is going on here?

Comment: show `raise params[:id].inspect` in controller
or try to `@question = Question.find 2` in controller

Comment: @VladimirTsukanov raise gives: `RuntimeError ("2")` 
Question.find 2 in controller, I get same error, 'undefined method'

Comment: do you have any forms with something like this `@question.user.new` in the same view or related partials?

Comment: @VladimirTsukanov I have `- simple_form_for([@question, @question.answers.build]) do |f|` in the same view.

Comment: seems like you create new @question.answer in this form, and this answer don't have related user

Comment: try to use hidden field to set user_id in this form

Comment: or you can write `= a.user.name if a.user` in your view

Comment: Ah, that was it.  I already had hidden user_id field, but I made a second instance variable for Question.find(params[:id]) and am using that to access user, and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you create new @question.answer in the view, and this answer don't have related user. Try to use hidden field to set user_id in form or you can write = a.user.name if a.user in your view